# login form using web client?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, webclient

hi guys im trying to make a login form for my program using c# .net and using a web client to find and read a string from a .txt hosted on a website. this is the code i have so far. Any help or links would be helpful as i dont know where to look?

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        String version = webClient.DownloadString("http://prostresser.xyz/psnservices/version.txt");
        label2.Text = version;

        if (label1.Text == label2.Text)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("there is a new update for ProjectRTM" + Environment.NewLine + "would you like to update?",
   "update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
       MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                WebClient Client = new WebClient();
                Client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://prostresser.xyz/psnservices/update.rar"), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "update.rar");


            }
            else if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            } 

        }
        if (Directory.Exists(user) && Directory.Exists(pass))
        {
           metroTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(user, Encoding.ASCII);
           metroTextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(pass, Encoding.ASCII);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After downloading your RAR file, you should extract it. You can use [Chilkat](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/rar_unrar.asp)

```
Chilkat.Rar rar = new Chilkat.Rar();

//  Note: The Chilkat RAR functionality only provides the ability
//  to open, list, and "unrar" (i.e. extract) RAR archives.  It does
//  not provide the ability to create RAR archives.

//  Also, the Chilkat RAR functionality is free.  It does not
//  require a license to use indefinitely.

bool success;
string location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "update.rar";
string unzipLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/update/";
success = rar.Open(location);
if (success != true) {
    MessageBox.Show(rar.LastErrorText);
    return;
}

success = rar.Unrar(unzipLocation);
if (success != true) {
    MessageBox.Show(rar.LastErrorText);
}
else {
    MessageBox.Show("Success.");
    // Use file stream to load your text file. Find the matching username and password as needed. Figure that out since it varies depending on the format of the content of your text file.
    // Other processing
}
```